# GNOME customizations with dconf-editor and potential breakages in future updates

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-tweaks

If i will edit some GNOME settings with dconf-editor for example in Ubuntu 21.04, will things break for example if i'll update to Ubuntu 21.10/22.04 in the future?

Comment: The only possible answer: It depends.

Comment: As for whether to use `dconf-editor` to change settings with it: GO WILD with it. I do. That's why that f*cker is there. Change all the things. It's not like installing crazy amounts of new software like a hirsute hippo in a candy shop. It's just config for your already installed programs. As for the future: rest assured, when you upgrade, you will have cleanup to do. This site is rife with questions about what broke after an upgrade. What do I do about that? I use LTS versions, ride them out as long as I please (~5 years max) and then do a clean install of a newer LTS.

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially asking "*will my bicycle tires need to be re-inflated next year?*"

Of course they will. Bicycles require maintenance. Software also requires maintenance.

Developers try to minimize breaking changes using several common methods. But that's not a promise of "no changes." The Gnome developers are in the mainstream on this.

If you want a Gnome that won't have changes for five years, use an LTS release of Ubuntu. If you want to stick with non-LTS, the price of newer software is occasional change.

Comment: Yeah but technically the answer could be well, if a setting is incompatible with a new version, it tends to be ignored, as opposed to let it break something... (I don't know if this is the case, but would be valuable to know.)

Comment: Quite true. Another option is to keep track of the changes you make, so you can find them again. It makes reverting to stock settings and troubleshooting much easier.

Comment: thanks for replies guys, I think I'll just revert everything to the default settings before updating

Comment: That is an excellent idea.